# How to prove that $\phi: \;\mathrm Mod(S_g)\to \mathrm Sp(2g, \mathbb{Z})$ is an epimorphism?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, mapping-class-groups

How do I prove that homomorphism $\phi : \; \mathrm{Mod}(S_g)\to \mathrm{Sp}(2g, \mathbb{Z})$ (induced by the action of mapping class group of a surface on integer homologies of a surface) is an epimorphism? My idea was to work with generators, but I was not able to prove it this way.

I would love to get detailed answers in order to understand this better.

Answer (score 3):

This is well-known material, so insted of a "detailed answer" let me give you a  standard reference. See

B. Farb and D. Margalit: *A primer on mapping class groups*, Theorem 6.4.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Francesco that for a detailed answer you should read Farb/Margalit, but for an executive summary:

The mapping class group is generated by Dehn twists, the symplectic group by transvections (elementary matrices). Dehn twists get mapped to transvections by the Torelli map (your $\phi.$)